# Mapbox simply can't find address

Tags: mapbox

I already asked the same thing to Mapbox support and it's been a week and no response, so here I am.

Here at my company we are developing a system that uses a delivery service to deliver products to our customers. This delivery service uses Mapbox to get the latitude and longitude of the customer's address so they can tell the exact spot where to deliver the order to their workers.

So we started using mapbox to get these required data but we are facing a problem here.

You see, for addresses here in the city of Natal, in Brazil, everything works fine, not a problem at all. But when there's a delivery to Parnamirim, a nearby city, mapbox service simply can't find the correct address. We filled everything correctly and still the results are not the ones we asked. Can anyone help-me with that?

For example, we want to find the coordinates of the following address: "Rua dos Pinheiros, 10, Encanto Verde. Parnamirim - RN" The zip code is "59149-594".

```
Street name: Rua dos Pinheiros
Number: 10
Neighborhood: Encanto Verde
City: Parnamirim
State: RN (Rio Grande do Norte)
ZIP Code: 59149-594
Country: Brazil
```

With this data, we send you the following query: https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/rua%20dos%20pinheiros%2010%20encanto%20verde%20Parnamirim%2059149-594%20BR-RN.json (I've hidden the access_token here, but it is present on the URL).

I've tried to add the `country=BR&language=BR` to the, but still facing the same problem.

If you search for this address on Google, it returns the correct one. But with Mapbox, it simply can't find the correct. This is happening with all addresses from Parnamirim. We don't know about other ones, but this is a big problem for us.

What can we do to fix it? Mapbox doesn't have addresses from Parnamirim in the db? Another crazy thing is that the coordinates are weird. In the first result from the above request, the coordinates takes us to the middle of the sea. Are those in the correct order?

Comment: You can always just use Apple's Geocoder to deal with addresses and coordinates, even if you are using Mapbox maps. Then use the coordinate on your maps.

Comment: When you request coordinates it can take some time for the Geocoder to return correct data and sometimes it will initially return (0 latitude, 0 longitude). This is in the ocean south of Nigeria. Is this what you see sometimes?

Comment: That's not the problem, actually. The problem is that Mapbox can't find the real address at all

Comment: I came here looking for the same, mapbox can't find an address in Argentina at all, for some reason even setting the correct language and country, it returns always empty for almost any LATAM country when looking for address, poi seems to be ok

Comment: @GabrielAzevedo I think is related to the language coverage by mapbox https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#language-coverage

Comment: Hey! But the funny thing is that it finds many addresses here. The problem is that none of those are the one I'm looking for. Even if I use the portuguese language, I still face the same problem. I've tried to contact them directly but no answers.

Comment: @GabrielAzevedo I just migrate to https://www.tomtom.com, this one have better support for spanish address, maybe portuguese is also supported as well, mapbox lacks on geocoding on lang differents than english

Comment: Hi, everyone! I'm facing the same problem. With Argentina... Do you find a solution or should I use another provider's GeoCoder?

Comment: I've decided to go with Places API on the project, not a single problem. Mapbox wasn't working at all and they provided us a terrible support. Maybe you should try another geocoder provider

Comment: @GabrielAzevedo tom tom works like a charm on spanish address and are cheaper than places api... check that out

Comment: Same problems with Milan... Azure GeoCoding service is working perfectly

Comment: Guys, try tomtom.com, its very cheap and probably support well your countries, @GabrielAzevedo have in mind that Places API is insanely expensive...